# Problems loading assets with Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have some troubles loadings my css sheets with Symfony.

I'm using this in app\Resources\views\base.html.twig to load ccs files in web\bundles\app\css :

```
{% block stylesheets %}

        {% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}

{% endblock %}
```

Doing this throw an exception : "Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_2c8c367_0" as such route does not exist.") in base.html.twig at line 10

This works, css load and no exception thrown :

```
{% block stylesheets %}

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bundles/app/css/bootstrap.css">

{% endblock %}
```

Can someone help me understand why the first code dosn't works ? I haven't used Symfony since 6 month but I'm sure that's how I used to load css.
 [Here is the doc about it.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to empty your web/bundles folder first then run `php app/console assets:install web/ --symlink` and continued by `php app/console assetic:dump`

If the errors still occurs, try to recheck every css files included